# mediaelement.js shoutcast stream inf Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, mp3, mediaelement.js, shoutcast

I would like to use mediaelement to play shoutcast internet radio stream.

The problem is that Firefox does not support html5 mp3. It would be nice to add failsafe flash player, or any other solution.

Answer (score 1):

mediaelement.js has a built in flash player as a fallback. What issues are you having with it?

For our Shoutcast stream, we use "http://255.255.0.0/;stream.nsv" as the audio source (with a real IP address, of course). The semicolon is required and is what tells Shoutcast to deliver the stream instead of the admin page to the browser.